# How do you initialize the target cpu using the usbWiggler API?

Tags: integrated-circuit, cpu, usb-device, jtag

I'm trying to use [usbWiggler](http://cboardtest.com) to communicate with a board that has 4 ICs.

[image]

Through the [usbWiggler API](http://cboardtest.com/?page_id=30) I have been trying to write and read from the board. However the CPU on the board is not one of the recognized CPUs and although the API giving the option to name it "UNKNOWN" the initialization of the API (through `MacraigorApi_InitializeTarget()`) fails with "Invalid Parameter" error.
[image]

Dose anyone know how to fix this?
I tried contacting their support but they never reply.

---

**Edit 01**

---

The CPU is Motorola 68hc11.

Comment: You are probably out of luck , usually at this point I start trying different inputs to see what works and what doesn't. If you have some example code, then run that and find out where yours doesn't work. Are you sure you've defined your array right?

Comment: There are several problems here: it is not clear what you mean by "initialize", you can't do much with a jtag target that you do not know or have not discovered details of, and you will not be able to get much help here when you neglect to even identify the CPU in question.

Comment: @laptop2d The array is right according to the API docs. But it seems it's a bug in their code that doesn't allow you to specify the CPU as "UNKNOWN" if it is the first in the chain.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I added info on the CPU. The thing is it's not one of the recognized CPUs according the the usbWiggler API. also regarding the "initialize" process, it seems it's only preparing the API to deal with the CPU. By the way my background on dealing with CPU on such low level is minimum, so please excuse my ignorance.